# jsPlumb is drawing connections with incorrect offset when using jQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jsplumb

In my project I'm using jQuery UI Sortable for reordering lists. 
You can find working example on http://jsfiddle.net/kerzad19/6/ 
It is possible to change order of blocks and items inside of blocks. This is working fine. 
 
Now I want to draw connections between items, using jsPlumb. I know that jsPlumb requires position:absolute for draggable divs. But Sortable requires position:relative for reordering elements.

```html
 jsPlumb.recalculateOffsets($(ui.item).parents(".block"));
```

I tried to recalculate offsets, but it didn't help.
How can I fix offset for jsPlumb connection?